# How can I point to the state of something in the past (like my skills 6 months ago)

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

For example, how can I ask to rate my English skill the way it was 6 months ago.

I'm almost sure it's wrong but something like:

> How would you rate my English at 6 months ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to say what you want to say with that sentence. Here are just two of them:

> On a scale from one to ten, how would you evaluate my English speaking skills as they were six months ago?
>
> On a scale from one to ten, how would you evaluate my English as it was six months ago?

Your original sentence might work. The only serious problem that I see with it is the phrase *at 6 months ago*. That just doesn't sound like natural English in the context of your example.